# ownCloud is NOT installed. download of ownCloud source file failed

Tags: php, ssl

When i try to install MyCloud (.org) on my providers server it says the following:

---

Warning: rename(tmp-owncloud1379778454/owncloud,./owncloud): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in E:\HostingSpaces\Rekum\cloud.jailbreaking.nl\wwwroot\setup-owncloud.php on line 108
ownCloud

Error

ownCloud is NOT installed
download of ownCloud source file failed.
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failedSSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

---

Can anyone help me solve this? I know its a Windows server, but I do not have the privilege to send commands or something. Basically I only have FTP access and database access.

If you want to try to install, you can check the install over here:

[My Website](http://cloud.jailbreaking.nl/setup-owncloud.php)

Thank you!
Joost

Answer (score 0):

Please download the .zip version from owncloud.org. Unpack it manually locally and upload the complete folder with ftp. This should work